# Populating Childnode list: Linq confusion and separation of concerns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, subsonic3

I am trying to implement a tree view in my application. I am using MVC2 Preview 1, and SubSonic 3 SimpleRepository. I am new to both MVC and Linq.

My problem is that I am not sure how to add a list of child nodes to the model record that I am passing back to the View. So I have added a IEnumerable called Children to my model class that I populate in the controller action:

```
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {

    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [SubSonicIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<Category> Children { get; set; }

}
```

Then in the controller action, I pull all of the records and iterate through updating the Children member:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var categories = _repo.All<Category>();

        foreach (var c in categories)
        {
            c.Children = from p in _repo.All<Category>()
                                               where p.ParentId == c.ID
                                               orderby p.Name
                                               select p;
        }   
        return View(categories);     
     }
```

My 2 questions are #1 Why does this not work? Outside of the scope of the loop my changes are lost. #2 In a general sense, is this the right approach? Putting this code in the controller feels like a hack.

Comment: I don't think you've been clear as to what specifically is not working?  I agree that this logic should not be in the controller.  Sounds like the repository should ensure that the model class is hydrated properly.

Comment: Stepping through the foreach with the debugger i can see c.Children get set. However, the contents of categories does not change. My question is why does this not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for why it doesn't work, I suspect deferred execution is getting you.  If you wrap the Linq query like so`( from ... select p).ToList()` it will cause the query to be evaluated.

Regarding the approach, it is data access in the presentation tier, so generally speaking, that would be something to avoid.